# Does BOO run on WinRT (Windows 8 Apps)?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, boo

Can I compile BOO on WinRT for a Windows 8 App? Have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Someone would have to write a Boo IDE/compiler that was deployed as an application to the Windows Store in order to ***compile*** on Windows RT (ARM).  A quick search shows 2676 apps with "Boo" as a keyword (really?!) on the Windows Store, but none for a combination of "Boo and Compiler".

Would it be possible, at least on Windows 8 (vs. RT)? probably.  The Boo compiler would need to essentially implement language projections to the Windows Runtime in the same way as .NET, C++, and JavaScript do in Windows 8 today.   From the [commits on the github](https://github.com/bamboo/boo/commits/master) project, there doesn't appear to be activity in that regard, but it seems like Windows Phone 7.x is in their sights.

Comment: 2676 apps with "Boo" as a keyword? Amazing :-) Just illustrates why one should be mindful of what a search engine is likely to throw up when deciding on a name for a programming language. (Then again it is built on a framework called ".net")